# Docker MySQL exits after docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run docker in Ubuntu, and I have a problem with MySQL. I always get this:

> "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe" 5 seconds ago Exited (0).

I have installed this docker image without problems on two machines, but this one doesn't work.

**Docker Info:**

Client:

```
Version: 1.8.1 
API version: 1.20 
Go version: go1.4.2 
Git commit: d12ea79 
Built: Thu Aug 13 02:35:49 UTC 2015 
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Server:

```
Version: 1.8.1 
API version: 1.20 
Go version: go1.4.2 
Git commit: d12ea79 
Built: Thu Aug 13 02:35:49 UTC 2015 
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

UNAME -A:

```
Linux xps 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add which commands you used to run the container? You said you were using compose, can you add your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: We need the docker-compose, Dockerfiles and maybe you could also try to do `docker log [container-name]` to know more about exiting. Maybe you're using a different entry-point/command.